# Using OR and AND in COUNTIFS

Tags: excel

I would like to use "OR" and "AND" in my COUNTIFS for Excel.

Specifically I am counting depending whether two columns have specific elements:

```
(If Column 1 has text "A" or "B" AND If Column 2 has text "C" or "D" ) count it.
```

So both columns have to fulfill the "OR" criteria in order for it to be counted. This was my original attempt:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B5:B94,{"A","B"},G5:G159,{"C","D"}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to change the comma in the second array (or the first, doesn't matter which one, just not both) to a semicolon

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B5:B159,{"A","B"},G5:G159,{"C";"D"}))
```

This then turns your count if into a matrix. Edited to make range sizes the same

Comment: Well spotted, so he would just need to change B94 to B159

Answer (score 0):

First off, the ranges in a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) are going to have to be the same. I've used rows 5:159 for both.

Your formula is seeing the logic as **in-line**. It is reading it as "for every 'A' in column B there must be a 'C' in column G or for every 'B' in column B there must be a 'D' in column G". You want it to read like "for every A in column B there must be either a 'C' or 'D' in column G or for every 'B' in column B there must be either a 'C' or 'D' in column G. To do this, you have to change the direction it thinks one of the sets of values are in.

The [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) can flip one of the constant sets; e.g. if Excel thinks it is reading **{"A", "B"}** as rows then it will think that it is reading TRANSPOSE(**{"C", "D"}**) as columns. This is the way to achieve four combinations; not two.

Either of these standard formulas should do.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B5:B159, {"A","B"}, G5:G159, TRANSPOSE({"C","D"})))
'alternate
=SUM(INDEX(((B5:B159="A")+(B5:B159="B"))*((G5:G159="C")+(G5:G159="D")), , ))
```

Normally this is where I type something like *fill down as necessary*- but that formula really isn't going anywhere.

[image: count_and_or.PNG]